# What happens to the crew in The Lost World: Jurassic Park?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost-world-jurassic-park

In The Lost World: Jurassic Park there is a scene where the ship which brings the T-Rex to San Deigo has no crew inside it. How come all the crew members are dead if the dinosaur was still inside the cage?